# Can not size a List in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, flowlayout

I want to use a JPanel with FlowLayout. 
adding to it a 2 awt lists.
Then I will add this JPanel (named DualListPanel) to a JFrame.

```
public class DualListPanel extends JPanel{
    private List list1 = new List();
    private List list2 = new List();

    public DualListPanel(){
        list1.setSize(500, 100);//Not working
        list2.setSize(500, 100);//No tworking
        add(list1);
        add(list2);
    }
}
```

Frame :

```
public class SecondFrame extends JFrame{
    private DualListPanel dualList = new DualListPanel();

    public SecondFrame(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        add(dualList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(600, 250);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SecondFrame secondFrame = new SecondFrame();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can not set a size to the lists ?
Using awt list, FlowLayout to JPanel is required.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using setPreferredSize? Default layout managers in Java use setPreferredSize, not setSize

Comment: Start by not using `java.awt.List` and start using a `javax.swing.JList` instead.  Once you've got that, you can use a `GridLayout` to cause the lists to occupy more space and a `JScrollPane` to allow for overflow

Comment: Have a look at [How to use lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), [How to use scroll panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html), [Laying out components in a container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), [How to use various layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html) and [A visual guide to layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better  [Laying out components in a container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), [How to use various layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html) and [A visual guide to layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use a JPanel with FlowLayout. adding to it a 2 awt lists

Don't use an AWT List in a Swing application.

Instead use a `JList`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information and working examples.

The width of the list will be determined by the width of the largest item added to the `JList`. Or you can alter this by using the `setPrototypeCellValue(...)` method.

The height will be determined by the number of items added to the list. Or you can alter this by using the `setVisibleRowCount()` method.

So the point is don't try to control the size. Use the methods of the API to provide hints for the `JList` to determine its own size.

Comment: Why we should not use Awt in swing application ?
Where is the problem ?
The FlowLayout and all layouts are awt objects !!
I said that I want to use awt list.
Why you ansewred if you can not solve this problem ??

Comment: @MohammedAit, I answered because I did solve the problem. You are welcome for the  help.